# Q:TypeError: First argument must be a string or Buffer,the easy bug with the node,

Tags: node.js

When I create the first serve for the first node practise, it shows the error that:

> _http_outgoing.js:458
>       throw new TypeError('First argument must be a string or Buffer');"

I'd want to know how to deal with?

```js
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var mime = require('mime');
var url = require('url');   

function  serve(request,response) {
    var urlobj = url.parse(request.url,true);
    var pathname = urlobj.pathname;
    if(pathname =='/'){
        response.statusCode = 200;             
        response.setHeader('Content-Type','text/html;charset=utf-8');   
        response.setHeader('keyname','zfpx'); 
        fs.readFile('index.html',function (err,data) {
            response.write(data);  
            response.end();
        });
    }else {
        static(pathname,response);
    }

    function static(url,response) {
        response.setHeader('Content-Type',mime.getType(url)+';charset=utf-8');   
        fs.readFile(url.slice(1),function (err,data) {
            response.write(data);  
            response.end();
        });
    }
}

var server = http.createServer(serve);
server.listen(8080,'localhost');
```

Comment: Do you have a line in the `error` pointing to a line in your code?

Comment: yeah, the error line is :"response.write(data);" in the function static ;the whole note is ollow as:TypeError: First argument must be a string or Buffer
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.write (_http_outgoing.js:458:11)
    at ReadFileContext.callback (F:\study\pro1\3.HTTP\3.HTTP.js:35:22)
    at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterOpen [as oncomplete] (fs.js:366:13)

Comment: Can you do `fs.readFile(url.slice(1),function (err,data) {console.log(err);console.log(data);})`?

Comment: OH！Thanks，I've found the reason.There is a icon which is dismissed.

Comment: You will do that for everybody. No thanks needed. %)P Glad.